# Transfer chat to queue from Einstein Bot

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, sfdc

I am trying to route chat from einstein bot to a queue. I am calling an omni channel flow to achieve the same thing but the flow fails with the following error -
This Route Work invocable action did not create a valid Pending Service Routing.
This same flow doesn't fail when I debug it with same user which I have specified in the bot configuration.

Tried creating PSRs manually.